# my project java code has some syntax error but it is maven build working success, it makes me confused

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

my project java code has some syntax error that wrong package name , like below :

```
// below line make java problem, The declared package "com.test.as.utils" does not match the expected package "com.test.as"
package com.test.as.utils; 


import java.io.File;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.pointi.ivr.FileWatchdog;
import com.pointi.ivr.FileWatchdogListener;
import com.pointi.ivr.FileWatchdogThread;

public abstract class AbstractReloadConf implements FileWatchdogListener {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbstractReloadConf.class);
protected FileWatchdogThread watchdogThread;

synchronized
private void initialize(String configFile) throws Exception {
    watchdogThread = new FileWatchdogThread("ConfigWatchdog");
    watchdogThread.addFileWatchdog(new FileWatchdog(configFile));
    watchdogThread.setFileWatchdogListener(this);
    watchdogThread.setDelay(1000);
}

public  void configureAndStart(String configFile) throws Exception {
    initialize(configFile);
    watchdogThread.start();
    parseConfigFile(new File(configFile));
}

@Override
public void onChanged(File file) {
    try {
        parseConfigFile(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("", e);
    }         
}

protected abstract void parseConfigFile(File file) throws Exception;
}
```

another class  use this abstract class for extend and it is make java error too.
like below :

```
package com.test.as.vmsc.server;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import org.ini4j.Wini;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.test.ivr.AppConfig;
// below line make java problem,The import com.test.as.utils cannot be resolved
import com.test.as.utils.AbstractReloadConf;

// below line make java problem, AbstractReloadConf cannot be resolved to a type
public class SceVmscReloadConf extends  AbstractReloadConf {
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SceVmscReloadConf.class);
private static SceVmscReloadConf singletone = new SceVmscReloadConf();
private static final List<String> routeNumberList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();

public static SceVmscReloadConf getInstance() {
    return singletone;
}

public void addRouteNumber(String routeNumber) {
    routeNumberList.add(routeNumber);
}

@Override
// below line make java problem, The method parseConfigFile(File) of type SceVmscReloadConf must override or implement a supertype method
protected void parseConfigFile(File file) throws Exception {
    Wini ini = new Wini(file);

    String voicecertMode = ini.fetch("VOICECERT", "MODE", String.class);
    if(voicecertMode != null) {
        AppConfig.getInstance().setVariable("voicecertMode", voicecertMode);
    } else {
        AppConfig.getInstance().setVariable("voicecertMode", "0");
    }
    
    String voicecertOnlyDisable = ini.fetch("VOICECERT", "VOICE_ONLY_DISABLE", String.class);
    if(voicecertOnlyDisable != null) {
        AppConfig.getInstance().setVariable("voicecertOnlyDisable", voicecertOnlyDisable);
    } else {
        AppConfig.getInstance().setVariable("voicecertOnlyDisable", "0");
    }


}
```

I thought this code would fail to maven build (goal is clean, install) because it has some java problem (wrong package path)

But maven build is suceeds.

I don't understand it. I checked pom.xml but I didn't find abnormal setting.

Maybe modify package path to correctly problem is solve and code make clean, but I want know why this code succeeded to maven build in spite of has java problem.

Comment: Package `com.test.client.utils` would have to be in a `com/test/client/utils` folder. The package for the `com/test/clint` folder would be `com.test.clint`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you, guys. i understood how to fix java problem in this case but i wonder to why maven build was sucess in spite have java problem. if anyone kown it is add commet. plz

Answer (score 0):

please rename the class to public abstract class Test {}  (with T uppsercase)
changes the imports
mvn clean install => should be ok
on eclipse top of the menu click on project -> clean => this should remove the errors

Comment: thank you, guys. i understood how to fix java problem in this case but i wonder to why maven build was sucess in spite have java problem.  if anyone kown it is add commet. plz